# Need generic xpath for the following html code

Tags: python, xpath, html-parsing

Following is the HTML code for which I need a unique XPath.

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Type</legend>
<input id="applyremotewhite" name="rvaluetype" checked="checked"     value="white" type="radio">
<label for="applyremotewhite">White List</label>
<br>
<br>
<input id="applyremoteblack" name="rvaluetype" value="black" type="radio">
<label for="applyremoteblack">Black List</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
```

I need something like [@label = 'White List'] so that I need not write multiple xpaths in my code. I want to pass values like White List and Black List from a function.

Comment: This is HTML. Why not use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I am very new to this. Will read about BeautifulSoup.

Comment: If you are new, then how did you know what XPath is, or why did you think you needed it?

Comment: @SaurabhThakkar If you use beatifulsoup then you can select `label` inside `fieldset` where `for` attribute is `applyremotewhite` and then `text` inside that label.

Answer (score 0):

`@label` references to an attribute and not a text node. You want refer to the text content. E. g. you should find the label with this text with `fieldset/label[text() = 'White List']`.

Comment: its fieldset not fileset

Comment: I am very new to this. Your suggested answer does not work.

Comment: I corrected the typo as you suggested and it works. However, the node selected is not unique. Firebug says that it finds 3 matching nodes with the xpath you suggested.

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi: Thank you, I've corrected the term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index as below to get the expected node if multiple matching nodes are returned.

```
(label[text() = 'White List'])[N]
```

'N' would be the index of node you want to work upon.

Comment: Despite using the index like (label[text() = 'White List'])[1], it still says 2 matching node found

Comment: It is impossible for index to return more than one element, you might not have added ( ) round brackets before and after xpath string.

Comment: (//label[text() = 'White List'])[1]